# IntelliJ can't resolve packages from ShadowJar plugin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I am working on a kotlin library for my physics class. It should allow easy calculations with vectors and matrices, and eventually allow to make physics simulations.

I am using the [glm](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/glm) library for the maths implementation (I am planning to wrap those classes with my own API). So, I decided to use gradle to manage my dependencies easier.

I want this library to be as easy to use, especially for people who aren't experienced developers. Ideally, The entire library would build to one single jar file that can simply be included in any new project.

When I tried to build the jar, I noticed that the glm library wasn't included in the jar, so even though everything compiled fine, I got exceptions in runtime for anything that tried to use glm (APIs that weren't dependent on glm worked fine in runtime though).

After doing some research, I found the [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin for building "fat" jar that contains all the dependencies. After using it, the resulting jar did contain everything needed so everything compiled and ran successfully. However, IntelliJ idea couldn't resolve anything from this jar. Everything compiles and runs fine, but the IDE thinks that the library doesn't exist.

I have no idea how to solve this issue. I tried looking online, but couldn't find anything useful. Do you have an idea how to create this one jar file that contains everything you need to use the library, and the IDE can resolve and autocomplete for it?

Here are the relevant screenshots:

My library's demo APIs and build.gradle:
[image]

A demo project using the library. I copied the jar file created by the `shadowJar` task and linked it to the project. As you can see, IntelliJ can't resolve anything about my library, but when I build and run, everything works as expected.
[image]

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: `I copied the jar file created by the shadowJar task and linked it to the project` How?  Does it appear in your `External Libraries`?  Is this a gradle project?  (the demo one)

Comment: Yes. Demo is a gradle project. The other one is just a sample non gradle project. I created the jar by running `shadowJar` in `Demo` and copied the jar file to the sample project, linked it by using Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Jars or Directories...

Comment: And it's in `External libraries`?  Can you see the classes when you expand the jar in the project view?

Comment: yes. As I said, it compiles and runs fine. Only IntelliJ fails to recognize this

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?